# Basic cooking recipe app for Android without adverts?

Tags: android

I have a number of recipes as simple text files on my (Linux-) PC, and at the moment I copy them to my phone via WeChat, which is handy in the kitchen. I'm thinking about writing my own, simple app, something with a SQLite database, an interface to view, create and edit recipes, ingredient list, perhaps a shopping list as well.

But before I do that, I would like to know if there are any apps out there. No pictures or network should be needed, and I **really** don't want to look at advertising; I don't mind paying a modest fee. From what I have been able to find so far, they all have adverts, in-app purchases or daft recommendations - and in some cases they don't allow you to enter your own recipes.

I found one promising one, called [Bites, on F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/packages/caldwell.ben.bites/), but it doesn't seem to do anything and there are no instructions. Any suggestions?

Comment: Several [in my list here](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/health_food_recipes#group_975) (concentrate on those having either a yellow star (no trackers, no ads) or the F-Droid icon (same for the F-Droid version)). I count about 8 possible candidates matching that (excluding those working with Nextcloud, whichh is what I use).

Comment: @Izzy Brilliant - that's a very useful list, thank you!